# What is the best way to display "Currency" format in browsers correctly?

Tags: javascript

I would like to find out the best way to display "Currency" format. Could someone give me a good advice for that? I've known that there are two ways such as toLocaleString or using accounting.js. Which one is better?

```
const num=123.45;
num.toLocaleString('en-US',{style:'currency', currency:'NZD'});
```

Comment: code please ! have you tried threw any of one(toLocaleString or accounting.js)?

Comment: I doubt there's a best way without knowing more. For example if you can't (or don't want to) import external libraries, accounting.js is not viable. In other words, this could be a matter of opinion.

Comment: My code is : 
<code>const num=123.45;
num.toLocaleString('en-US',{style:'currency', currency:'NZD'});
</code>

Comment: You will have to be clearer in your criteria for `best`. If you've tried something and it didn't work or have limitations, [edit] your try in your question. Right now it's unclear what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `Intl.numberformat`

usage :

```
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
});
formatter.format(2500); // $2,500.00
//the default value for minimumFractionDigits depends on the currency
```